# Custom maven plugin, spring and configuration file

Tags: spring, maven, maven-plugin

I wrote a Maven plugin which instantiates a Spring context. I want to be able to configure the Spring context using a properties file in the project classpath. In the plugin context XML I have:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
    <value>classpath:configurator.properties</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

When I run the proper plugin goal in the Maven project using my plugin, Spring can't read the **configurator.properties** file from the **target/classes** folder.

How should I configure my mojo to allow Spring running in my plugin to read the properties file from the project classpath?

Comment: Can you give a little bit more information? How is your mojo annotated? Which phases runtime etc. which kind of project annotation? Are you running from a single module build or a multi-module build? Have you tried your code within a unit test?

Comment: Hi. Mojo is annotated with: `@goal create-partner-group, @phase process-classes`. I'm running it from single module build in separate maven module using this plugin. I didn't try to test it with maven-plugin-testing-harness but when I run other unit tests with configurator.properties